# Android and http communications

Tags: php, android, http, chat, instant-messaging

I have looked on here and anddev for a suitable response, but haven't found anything suitable.
Here is the question: My friend has an instant chat application with iPhone, and since I have some basic android experience he asked me to check out "porting" it to Android. So before I set up the UI, I decided to look into php which I don't have much experience with. I know the UI will need an array to call contacts, but I'm not sure about retrieving the information from the php.

How do I know if I can use his script or not? I haven't found any good tutorials about Android and Php - has anyone found one?

I might as well learn this stuff now because my next app will require an online database to be used in it - I know his has users and passwords, and he'd like to be able to send im's between iPhone and Android clients.

Thanks for any help you may provide!

**EDIT:**

Yes, this issue is more related to http requests from android to a remote server; I have changed the tags and subject accordingly, but would still appreciate a guide to android-friendly php writing. Thank you!

Comment: this is not really about PHP (server implementation does not matter), but rather about making HTTP requests from android to a remote server and parsing the response. Anyways, I'd recommend JSON as interchange format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't `Android-Friendly PHP` but there is mobile friendly PHP.  Basically, you need your PHP scripts to emit something that is easy to parse in an application (like XML or JSON) rather than the standard HTML.  After that, all you need to do is figure out what the API should look like on the server side.  That is, what functions does the server need to provide and how is it going to provide them.  Are you going to use simple HTTP authentication or are you going to use something more complicated?

With regards to his chat application, I would imagine that if he already has an iPhone version, then you won't need to mess with the sever side at all.  All you need to do is figure out what URLs and parameters to use for what operations.  You also need to ask him what data format his server uses.  If it's XML, you need to find an XML parser, if it's JSON then you need to find a JSON parser etc. (there are plenty of tutorials on how to do both in Android via Google).  I would start by asking him, at a high-level, not with Objective-C specifics, how his chat application communicates with the sever.  You can then use that to build your application to communicate in the same manner.

Comment: Thank you for the response! 

I'll have to construct all of the server-side functions for my own app when I get around to it. Thanks for the insight regarding that, it's quite valuable.

Comment: As for his chat app, I do have his url information and parameters. This is where my searches confused me - apparently iPhone and Android are not compatible, because of iPhone's use of Objective-C? What high-level communications options are there that are compatible with both Mobile OSs? (more a question for my own, than his I admit - since his is already built). Thanks again for the input.

Comment: @Spanky, you are correct that iPhone and Android use different languages but because you are using a remove server, compatibility is not an issue.  When you are transmitting information over the internet (with very few exceptions) transmission is usually accomplished via a standard protocol such as XML or JSON.  The implementation language is not relevant.

Comment: Is it possible not to have a protocol? Because apparently his php returns a text data with a character delimiter -  how does Android integrate this type of communication?

Comment: Well, that itself is a protocol.  You'll have to parse that data yourself unless somebody has written an Android-compatible parser for that format.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.

Is there a good 'how-to' that you could refer me to?